# fullPage layout with collapsible layoutUnits doesn't display the buttons used to collapse

Tags: jsf, primefaces

It's already showing a simple full page layout with each layoutUnit and so on, but not any button. The XHTML page follows:

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="north">
                <h:form>
                    <p:growl id="messages" />
                    <p:menubar model="#{menuCategoriaMB.model}" />
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="275" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <h:form>
                    <div id="west">
                        <ui:insert name="west"></ui:insert>
                    </div>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit id="layout_center" position="center">
                <h:form>
                    <div id="content">
                        <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
                    </div>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="400" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <h:form>
                    <div id="east" style="padding-left: 45px;">
                        <ui:insert name="east"></ui:insert>
                    </div>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <h:form>
                    <div id="south">
                        <ui:insert name="south"></ui:insert>
                    </div>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

I'm using JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 5.0. Thank you.

P.S.: Had to omit the `<h:head>` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to show the buttons for closing and collapsing I believe you must set the `header` attribute for each `p:layoutUnit` you want to close/collapse.